# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, attributes, nltk

I am working with Vader from the nltk package.
I've imported my dataset following the vader tutorial:

```
    list = []
    for line in open("C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\Uni\Tesi\PythonTest\paolo.txt","r").readlines():
        for value in line.split(","):
            list.append(value)
```

Then I've created the function to remove punctuation:

```
     def _words_only(self):
    text_mod = REGEX_REMOVE_PUNCTUATION.sub('', self.text)
    words_only = text_mod.split()
    words_only = [word for word in words_only if len(word) > 1]
    return words_only
```

But when I try to use the "words only" function I get this error

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-cbc12179c890> in <module>()
    ----> 1 _words_only(list)

    <ipython-input-13-68a545bbbaa4> in _words_only(self)
  1 def _words_only(self):
    ----> 2        text_mod = REGEX_REMOVE_PUNCTUATION.sub('', self.text)
      3        words_only = text_mod.split()


    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am really new to Python. Is it a problem in the importing process or is it something else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share your class ?
You are sending list as an argument to your words_only function. I think you should send string not list here.

Comment: Is `_words_only` part of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show where/how you created the function `_words_only()`, but the `self` argument indicates that you patterned it on a class method. You're evidently using it as a stand-alone function, like this:

```
_words_only(list)
```

I would advise you not to tackle classes yet if you can avoid it. Write your function like this:

```
def words_only(text):
    text_mod = REGEX_REMOVE_PUNCTUATION.sub('', text)
    words_only = text_mod.split()
    words_only = [word for word in words_only if len(word) > 1]
    return words_only
```

You should also know that your function is designed to process *one* string, not a list of them. In addition, don't use builtin names like `list` as variable names-- you're asking for a very confusing error in a day or two. Use a more informative name, or an abbreviation like `lst`:

```
lines = [] 
...

some_words = words_only(lines[0])
```

Since you actually want to work with the list of lines, apply the revised function to each one like this:

```
filtered_lines = [ words_only(line) for line in lines ]
```

If you had wanted to work with the entire contents of the file, you would read in your text like this:

```
myfile = open(r"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\Uni\Tesi\PythonTest\paolo.txt","r")
text = myfile.read()
myfile.close()
some_words = words_only(text)
```

Comment: The function works really well! But my dataset is a list of tweets and if I use the import process you suggested as result I have only one big list of words. I'd like to keep the tweets separated and then clean each of them. Using my import process and then a for cycle combined with the words_only function could be a solution?

Comment: Easy enough, now that I know what you're after! Edited the answer.